# Is the "composition" of two dense subsets of functions dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Given $F \subseteq C_C(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^p)$, $F$ is dense in $C_C(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^p)$ in the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Also given $G \subseteq C_C(\mathbb{R}^p, \mathbb{R}^s)$, $G$ is dense in $C_C(\mathbb{R}^p, \mathbb{R}^s)$ in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Is the set $G \circ F := \{g \circ f: g \in G, f \in F, g \circ f \in C_C(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^s)\}$ dense in $C_C(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^s)$? Note that $d, p, s\in \mathbb{N}$ are not necessarily equal. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The infinity norm is not a norm on that space.

Comment: @Joel When $d=p$ the answer is obvious since $f$ can be taken to be the identity map, which is obviously bounded and hence in $C(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^d)$. But when $d, p$ are not equal, I pretty much don't know where to start.

Comment: @zhw. Could you please point out why? Thanks.

Comment: Take $d=p=1.$ What is $\|x\|_\infty?$

Comment: @zhw. Oops, nice catch, thanks! Would it be better if I change $C$ into something like $C_C$ or $C_0$?

Comment: @michaelsjiyu are you sure the identity map is in your F? We can find approximations to the identity. Also, now that you added the compactly supported qualifier, we know for certain the identity isn’t in your space as it is not compactly supported

Comment: @Joel well I guess with the extra condition of support being compact, we just have to restrict our identity map to the compact subspace on which the function we are discussing is supported then. But I think the real problem is the dimensionality since even though this identity map would work it would only work when $d = p$.

Comment: Compositions of compactly supported functions need not be compactly supported, for example if $f(0)=c\ne 0$ and $g=0$, then $f\circ g=c\ne 0$ is not compactly supported when $g$ is defined on a noncompact space like $\mathbb R^n$. So the question has to be adjusted.

Comment: @Kalua Nice catch, thanks!